# How to stop evil site moderators? ⦋quite firmly closed⦌

Tags: near-future, apocalypse, zombies, secret-society, mythical-creatures

> **Moderator notice:** Everything that follows in this question, including the fake notice at the bottom, is an intentional joke. Please don't [take it seriously](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4532/627); it's meant in jest.

---

Imagine internet site. And keep in mind we are in Worldbuilding, so everything you are going to read is completely imaginary, alternate world.

This site is called ApocalypseBuilding and runs exactly like Worldbuilding does. People go there and discuss hypothetical questions how to take over the world, or how to cause apocalypse.

This site has site moderators. Lets give them names, shall we? So group of moderators are:

- ABC 226868
- L. German
- Monty Tame

Keep in mind, that above names are completely random as we are talking about alternate world and have [no connection whatsoever](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) to real world.

These people realize, that thanks to very topic of the site, they have all the information they need to take over the world.

Now, they are going to take a plan into action. The question is: **What can users of that site do in order to stop malevolent site moderators?**

The site is run by fictional company FrackExchange which fully trusts these moderators. Also keep in mind, that the site moderators can put on hold any question warning site users about the plan.

Even if such question can come up from highly reputated user with more than 19k score. (Call him Pavel, for complete randomness)

Can there be something done, or are people of ApocalypseBuilding doomed to complete apocalypse?

> **closed** as being anti-establishment by Croatian Tanasa♦, Phoebe Cellio♦, BobB♦, ABC 226868♦, JDlugosz♦ Feb 22 '17 at 07:52
>
> This question is seditious in nature and its existence cannot be tolerated. It cannot be salvaged, and has been closed in order to protect the site moderators from the community.
>
> Since this question cannot be reworded to fit the rules in the [help center](https://www.reddit.com/r/help/), there is no point in trying.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54725/discussion-on-question-by-pavel-janicek-how-to-stop-evil-site-moderators-quite) by an evil moderator.  *Bwahahaha*

Comment: Somebody actually flagged this as "unclear what you're asking" and it ended up in the VTC queue.  Was it done as a joke? or is it getting just a bit stuffy on the site?  Personally, I love this post.

Comment: @JBH Yeah, I saw that too... I'm glad though as I hadn't read the post before and had a good laugh now that I've seen it :D

Comment: I object to the site moderators being tagged as a secret society. Everybody knows that *There Is No Cabal*.

Comment: Glad this question is getting the re-attention it deserves. Can I suggest a tag edit to include [tag:space-whales]? It is currently used on one question! The eViL moderators will hate that!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

1. Down-vote everywhere they post
2. VTC all of their questions with the most demeaning reason: "**Unsure what you're asking**"
3. Create more questions about Zombie Whales - moderators hate Zombie Whales
4. Use Wikipedia [disambiguation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disambiguation_(disambiguation)) links for every single citation
5. Voting to re-open churlishly closed satirical questions
6. Put "[on hold]" at the end of the question titles so moderators don't bother reading them
7. Edit answers needlessly so that previously closed satirical questions are bumped to the top
8. Insist on continuously using the word "Zombie" where FrackExchange rules insist on using the word "Undead"

Comment: Going for a psychological warfare, huh ? Well +1 anyway

Comment: Added a link citation to the post for clarity. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @Zxyrra That is going to be my second to favorite link; right after googling "recursion".

Comment: Maybe stop using the site? And use another? (A.K.A REDDIT WB)

Comment: Putting "[on hold]" or "[closed]" at the end is a bit tricky. I dare you to try ;)

Comment: @Mołot Satisfied?

Comment: @Pᴇᴛᴇ Unicode for the win.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Close, but I still clearly see the difference ;) I prefer 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)

Comment: @Mołot I know, I know, but I didn't want to make it entirely too non-obvious. This way, if you look closely, there's a difference.

Comment: Instead of Wikipedia disambigulation, why not use the rather random links as seen in XKCD's "what if" questions for "Source".

Answer (score 21):

We have many questions here on ApocalypseBuilding that have very strong backgrounds in science or religion.  It's often a hard call whether a question belongs here or if it should be migrated to the parent FE such as Physics.FE, or Christianity.FE or Biology.FE.

It's time to turn that around.

The plans to take over the world need to be released in a series of questions on the parent sites for our tags.  The hard physics of how to build a laser beam with a frickin' shark attached to it should be addressed on physics.  The 100+ questions regarding how AIs take over the world should start to show up on ComputerPseudoscience.FE.  The questions about implementing those AIs should even be pushed to FrackOverflow itself!  Ways to co-opt entire religions should be moved to You Modea, Xianity.FE, Islamaphobia.FE, etc!

Of course there will be challenges.  If Phoebe Cellio♦ happens to also be a moderator on You Modea, she will likely be able to prevent our insurrection on that front.  But surely there are other fronts to fight on!

Failing all of this, the next solution is citogenesis.  We need to trick the moderators into using faulty information.  Fortunately, ApocolypseBuilding supports a lower standard of proof than many other sites (an essential feature which permits us to talk about made up worlds successfully).  Wikipedia articles should be easy to forge for this citogenesis process:

[image: XKCD]

If all of this fails, then we are truly doomed.  In this case, I hold the nuclear option and will use it if needed: Skeptics.FE

> ### Is ApocalypseBuilding trying to take over the world?
>
> There's a crazy theory about the ApocalypseBuilding Moderators trying to take over the world.  I read about it on Wikipedia.  Is this a spoof, or a real threat?

The skeptics are serious business, taking on just about [any question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27612/do-4-of-americans-say-they-believe-in-lizard-people) with rigor and ferocity.  Don't mess with Skeptics.FE!

Comment: I think this answer uses a few too many real-world Stack Exchange references to be a good fit for the question. It would be better if it referred to the corresponding FrackExchange sites instead. For example, the FrackExchange site for discussing the finer points of judaism would likely be *Yi Modea*, and the programming questions would probably go on *Stack Underflow*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Good call.  I updated them.  The only one I didn't mangle was Skeptics.SE.  A mere name mangling wont fool those guys!

Comment: You know, there is this SE site where people actually discuss how to build AI, they say it is for ["games"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXzNo0vR_dU).

Answer (score 13):

A *very* imaginative scenario. However we need to consider what their strengths are:

- They have pooled the information of the collective intelligence.
- Will follow the dastardly schemes that were created purely for the sake of story-lines.

I'm going to imagine that this "FrackExchange" site also allows for the creation of new FE topics and suggest an **ApocalypseFixing** frackexchange where we can, once again, pool our ideas but for positive ends.

We could also answer questions in such a way that one or more of the perpetrators must turn against the others in order to succeed and pit them against each other.

Comment: I spent half of the time trying to translate the names :p

Comment: Now I want to write a set of Apocalypse-Fixing questions to tag...

Answer (score 13):

While *P$_{EAT}$* (not to be confused with Pᴇᴛᴇ) has already mentioned most of the things the FrackExchange community must start doing immediately to save the world, you must remember that the e$_{vil}$ moderators are extremely powerful and can undo most of the undermining tactics mentioned by *P*$_{EAT}$. Here are some other things which the community must do in order to save the world from impending disaster.

**1- When not knowing the answer, an answer must still be posted.**

A quick visit to english.frackexchange.com and obnoxiously asking for a list of surreptitious, exuberant and vivacious-looking words would help a lot. Use circumlocution commonly in your answer and try to make your answer a non-answer. The e$_{vil}$ mods would be confounded and discombobulated infathomably, explicitly helping your cause!

**2- Initiate long arguments in comments to everything they post.**

Doing this commonly will make them hate you with fervor and passion and infuriate them beyond alleviation. Notice that this should be done with a pinch of salt, for sometimes, someone will get smoked unbearably and press that red button throwing you (the user) out of the TrackExchange community altogether!

**4- Post all answer in list fashion.**

Even when not required. Also, repeat your points over and over using different vocabulary.

**5- Make errors in numbering your list items.**

This would make them go bonkers and they would have to edit each of your lists in order to fix it. Furthermore, even when all the list items are numbered correctly, secretly ask fellow community members to post a comment saying *"Hehe. Look at your list numbering! I hope they will never notice :p ;)"* You can be certain each of them will read all the list numbers 10 times over and then they will all gather in their secret room to discuss in detail if the list numbers are really messed up or did the comment author play a joke at them.

**6- Delete your good answers.**

When your answers are marked *ACCEPTED*, just delete them. This will annoy the e$_{vil}$ moderators to the end of their wits. If they restore your answer, edit it to change the content entirely!

**7- Always upvote non answers and answers based entirely on personal opinions.**

Doing this especially with questions tagged zombie-whales, whale-zombies, undead-whales and whales-undead will have a profound negative effect on the well being of the e$_{vil}$ moderators, baffling them to no end.

**Important Note:** There were 3.72 other methods too, which only the community members will be able to read. Send your credit card number, all online passwords and bank account number to Eusta Igo if you cannot see them, and want access to them.

Comment: Hehe. Look at your list numbering! I hope they will never notice :p ;)

Comment: Never indeed ;) @PavelJanicek

Comment: #9 - Observe carefully when a user, a regular but far from a power house, let's call him azuremergus, comes along late and enters a seemingly rambling comment.  Said comment at first glance has little to nothing to do with the original post, in fact it isn't even a complete thought.  However, upon later reflection, everyone realizes the true importance of azuremergus's insights.  Ultimatelty, it becomes very clear that the solution is

Answer (score 0):

You post this exact same question on [meta.stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) where they are not moderators. It will get enough attention over there (given the number of eyes).

<sup>I originally though about posting on [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/), but that is currently a low volume beta site.</sup>